# How does Google Docs position the cursor when up or down keys are pressed?

Tags: google-docs, rich-text-editor

Unlike most rich text editors on the web, Google Docs doesn't use contenteditable and instead uses its kix-editor. While moving the cursor on left/right presses is simple, how do they position their cursor when a user presses up or down?

For example, when a paragraph is multiple lines, how does the cursor know what is "above" it?

Or going up or down across multiple paragraphs, in a situation where there is an empty line between them and the cursor manages to save its horizontal positioning, despite the fact that the empty line forces it to move all the way to the left?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the DOM in Google Docs, it appears they do their own laying out. That is to say, they measure paragraph lengths and split them into separate divs. Therefore, the idea of iterating through the different ranges in the div "above" the currently selected div is a finite problem, instead of potentially an infinite one (if the previous paragraph is immensely long).